# Airdrop option missing in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

For some reason when I use ActivityViewController from my app I don't get the option to share using Airdrop. If i use it from Chrome, I do get the option:

[image: ActivityViewController]

This is the code that I'm using:

```
NSMutableArray * items = [NSMutableArray new];
[items addObject:@"text for share"];
[items addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                  applicationActivities:nil];


[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
  .....
}];
```

But I only get this:

[image: From app]

How do I add the Airdrop option?

Comment: I see you're adding text and an image to your items, have you tried only using one or the other?

Comment: It sounds like airdrop might need a URL, can you convert your image to an NSURL using `fileURLWithPath`?

Comment: Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to send something over AirDrop the item will need to be a URL. I couldn't find the official documentation, but in this [Apple AirDrop Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) it states:

`URLs can be used as a simple way to transfer information between devices. Apps can easily parse a received URL to determine what action to take. After an app registers a URL scheme (including custom schemes), the system will know to launch that app when a URL of that type is received.`